# Running Total Field + Other Field in Running Total Field (crystal report)

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

How this work is done

Running Total Field=Running Total Field + Formula Filed

this work be done in Running Total Field

Answer (score 0):

Insert this formula in the Details Section

WhilePrintingRecords; NumberVar Amount := Amount + {Order.Amount};

taken from 
http://www.crystalkeen.com/articles/crystalreports/runningtotalvar.htm
The link explains in further detail. As you can see the guy explains how to do it using two variables one to reset the totals to zero on every break and another to store the running total.

if you have straight table where there are no sub totals OR categories then do not use the variable to reset the value. Only use the second formula.

hope that helps.

On a side note. There should be an easier way, in BO XI3 there is a prev function to get the value of the prev row. i use that to calc running totals.